# TAPI, lineInitialize and lineInitializeEx

Tags: delphi, tapi

I try to use **TAPI** in my **Delphi** project.
When I use lineInitializeEx instead of lineInitialize I get an error msg like "**Exception Processing Message c0000139 Parameters 168fc8 162820 75b4bf7c 75b4bf7c**"
The code with lineInitializeEx is :

```
  var
    initPrm: TLineInitializeExParams;
  begin
    FillChar(initPrm, SizeOf(initPrm), 0);
    initPrm.dwTotalSize := SizeOf(initPrm);
    initPrm.dwOptions := LINEINITIALIZEEXOPTION_USEEVENT; // or LINEINITIALIZEEXOPTION_USEHIDDENWINDOW
    if lineInitializeEx(lineApp, HInstance, lineCallback, 'TAPI sample', nDevs, tapiVersion, initPrm) < 0 then
```

and definition of TLineInitializeExParams is:

```
TLineInitializeExParams = record
    dwTotalSize,                                    
    dwNeededSize,                                   
    dwUsedSize,                                     
    dwOptions: Longint;                             
    Handles: THandleUnion;
    dwCompletionKey: Longint;                       
  end;
```

When I use lineInitialize

```
if lineInitialize(lineApp, HInstance, lineCallback, 'TAPI sample', nDevs) < 0 then
```

everything is OK.

Is there any idea ?

Comment: Where are you getting the TLineInitializeExParams class from? It isn't a standard Delphi class? Is this the JEDI wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be worth looking at TurboPower Async Professional, which is now open source. This is what we used to successfully implement a TAPI project.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/tpapro/

Comment: thanks for your advice.  
I write Win32 Service App. and I think TP Async TAPI comps. not good choice for service application. Also I couldn't find how can use TurboPower Async TAPI components via TCP, not ComPort. When I use ApdTapiDevice comp. it wants a ComPort.

Comment: That's because TAPI is the Telephony API and so is designed fur use with modems, which communicate via the COM Port. Of course, much of this is old technology now. For communicating via TCP/IP, use the standard Delphi TSocket components.

Comment: TAPI is very usefull for communication with PBXs. I'll use it for this. My PBX supports TAPI 2. So I want to use lineInitializeEx function. But I think I should use lineInitialize.

Comment: Now I've just use JEDI wrapper and lineInitializeEx function works fine. 
@_J_ : Thanks for your relation.